# Apps that access the internet crash when waking up from sleep

Tags: sleep-wake, crash

Whenever I wake my 2012 MBA 13" from sleep, **all apps that were accessing the internet before going to sleep crash**. This includes the streaming software Zattoo.app, Chrome.app, Firefox.app, etc.

None of the apps that do not access the internet are affected, such as Pages.app, MS Word, etc.

All software is up to date, including the OS that currently is at version 10.8.2.

I have repaired disk permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Starting up in “safe mode” performs some repairs:

> Shut down your Mac and wait 10 seconds. Press the power button.
>   Immediately after you hear the startup tone, hold down the Shift key.
>   You should press the Shift key as soon as possible after you hear the
>   startup tone, but not before.
>
> Release the Shift key when you see the gray Apple logo and progress
>   indicator (spinning gear). To leave safe mode, restart the computer
>   normally without holding down any keys during startup.

Also, run Disk Utility, Repair Disk. Sounds like network problem, though, which could be as simple as trashing network settings (writing down any you won't remember,) Restarting and inputting afresh ...

Comment: Thanks for the hints. Unfortunately we had no success with this. We are going to the genus bar this afternoon. Let's see what happens there ;)